# Utilize Socket.io to control desktop from mobile

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm not sure if this allowed on here but please let me know if it's not. I'm wondering if anybody could point me in the direction of some great learning resources for Socket.io. I'm particularly interested in learning how to use a mobile device as a controller for a desktop web-browser application. Any nudges in the right direction will be extremely welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great resource for learning [socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki)

As far as usage of mobile device as controller for a web-app is concerned, there are clients out there for Android etc which interact with Node.js and socket.io server.
[socket.io-java-client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) is a client for android which can serve this purpose for you. You can emit something from android to your server and from server to web-apps or from directly android to web clients.